# Expression for "be a little faster"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

Is there an expression for the following:

> A: Let's go for lunch.
>
> B: Okay.
>
> A: I am coming in a few minutes.
>
> B: Okay, but *be a little bit faster*

Do native speakers say this? Or is there a better expression or words construction for this?

Comment: I'd say: "Hurry up!"

Answer (score 6):

> A: Hey, I am coming.
>
> B: Okay, but *hurry up*.

"Hurry up" is the way this sentiment is most commonly expressed.

Comment: You are mistaken, I think. [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=but+hurry+up+.%2Cbut+hurry+.&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *but hurry up .,but hurry .*  shows that "but hurry up." occurs much less often than "but hurry."

Comment: Conversationally, I'd expect to hear "hurry up" at least as often as "hurry" - particularly as a terminal statement in a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The whole conversation is a bit odd to me.

First example: If A suggests going for lunch but won't be ready for a few minutes, then he or she is likely to say that upfront: *Let's go for lunch in a few minutes*.

Second example: If you use the present continuous for the future (*I'm coming in a few minutes*), you imply that you have already made plans or arrangements, which does not fit with the *Let's go for lunch.*

Third example: *In a few minutes* already seems quite fast to me. A shorter time than a few minutes is one minute or a few seconds, so why not something like: *(Why) can't we go now?*

Answer (score 1):

***FAST!*** should do the trick. No time to shout out a whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Polite:

> A: Let's go for lunch.
>
> B: Okay.
>
> A: I'll be there in a few minutes.
>
> B: Okay, but I haven't got much time. Do you think you'll be ready soon?

Familiar:

> A: Let's go for lunch.
>
> B: Okay.
>
> A: I'll be there in a few minutes.
>
> B: Okay, but hurry up!

Emergency:

> A: Let's go for lunch.
>
> B: Okay.
>
> A: I'll be there in a few minutes.
>
> B: NOW!!!